# How do delete rows where column matches any of set using SQL query?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am trying to delete rows where each column in the row is matched with giving key. Here, I want to do a bulk operation where I will delete all rows if its value matched in any of the list. We can loop through it and delete one by one, for example

> for(Entries entry: list)
>     // delete where column = entry

I am looking for above operation using SQL and Java to do as a batch operation. Something like,

> delete rows where column match any of list

```
public ResponseEntity deleteEntries(@RequestBody String ids) throws SQLException {
        String[] entries = ids.split(",");
        for(int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM  LIST_ITEMS WHERE ID = ? ");
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, ids[i]);
            preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        }
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

run the above in a batch, since I will be deleting 1000 to 10K items, how do I run above query in a batch ?

Comment: You could always pass the ids as an xml and delete from your table where the id is in subquery select ids from xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass the list in your query using IN key world, so instead of :

```
DELETE FROM  LIST_ITEMS WHERE ID = ?
```

you can use :

```
DELETE FROM  LIST_ITEMS WHERE ID IN (?)
                                 ^^
```

Your code can look like this :

```
String query = "DELETE FROM  LIST_ITEMS WHERE ID IN (?)";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
Array array = preparedStatement.getConnection().createArrayOf("VARCHAR", entries);
preparedStatement.setArray(1, array);
preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

Comment: IN, nice I tested it and it worked. quick question - IN operation is faster than the while right even if there are only 10 rows in a huge dataset ?

Comment: @bash exactly, its better to treat your operation directly in the RDBM instead of code.

Comment: Know that using an array with `IN` doesn't work on all database systems or JDBC drivers.

Comment: Exactly @MarkRotteveel this s a good point, for example for postgresql we have to use `ID = Any(?)`